# Excel Nested IF query

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a nested IF function that I've created and I'm trying to use.

```
=IF(AND(K2>=Summary!$D$1,I2>Summary!$A$8,J2>0),"Poor 
Performer",IF(AND(J2=0,F2>30),"Pause",IF(AND(J2=0,F2<30,I2>10),"High 
Spender",IF(OR(E2<Summary!$A$13,E2="-"),"Low Traffic 
Boost",IF(K2<Summary!$C$1,"Under Invested","No Change")))))
```

I'm trying to tweak the Low Traffic Boost section to have an additional condition so that the output is accurate.
This is what it was :

```
IF(OR(E2<Summary!$A$13,E2="-"),"Low Traffic Boost"
```

And I'm trying to change it into this.

```
IF(OR(AND (K2<=Summary!$D$1,E2<Summary!$A$13),
AND(E2="-,K2<=Summary!$D$1),"Low Traffic Boost"
```

However, I keep getting an error. Could you please help me out here? I'm not sure why my Nested IF with an AND , OR statement isn't working properly.

Comment: Your corrected version is missing closing brackets. Is that the whole change?

Comment: Hi Seth, yep, as Engineer Toast answered below, I missed out on a closing bracket after the second function below which was the error in my statement.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the formula to a text editor and try adding line break to see what's wrong.

```
=IF(
    AND(K2>=Summary!$D$1,I2>Summary!$A$8,J2>0),
    "Poor Performer",
    IF(
       AND(J2=0,F2>30),
       "Pause",
       IF(
          AND(J2=0,F2<30,I2>10),
          "High Spender",
          IF(
             OR(E2<Summary!$A$13,E2="-"),
             "Low Traffic Boost",
             IF(
                K2<Summary!$C$1,
                "Under Invested",
                "No Change"
               )
            )
         )
      )
    )
```

Every `IF` statement has three arguments. Most of the time, that's another `IF` statement but that's OK. Each one uses parentheses `( )` to capture it's three arguments. Now do the same for your formula.

```
IF(
   OR(
      AND(K2<=Summary!$D$1,E2<Summary!$A$13),
      AND(E2="-,K2<=Summary!$D$1),
      "Low Traffic Boost"
```

It looks like you want to replace the `IF` statement that can return `Low Traffic Boost` so this isn't a complete formula, just a fragment. The problem is that you didn't use any parentheses to close the `OR` statement. It should look like this:

```
IF(
   OR(
      AND(K2<=Summary!$D$1,E2<Summary!$A$13),
      AND(E2="-,K2<=Summary!$D$1)
     ),
  "Low Traffic Boost"
```

I added a closing parantheses between the second `AND` and the comma `,`. The whole formula, then, should look like this:

```
=IF(
    AND(K2>=Summary!$D$1,I2>Summary!$A$8,J2>0),
    "Poor Performer",
    IF(
       AND(J2=0,F2>30),
       "Pause",
       IF(
          AND(J2=0,F2<30,I2>10),
         "High Spender",
         IF(
            OR(
               AND(K2<=Summary!$D$1,E2<Summary!$A$13),
               AND(E2="-,K2<=Summary!$D$1)
              ),
            "Low Traffic Boost",
            IF(
               K2<Summary!$C$1,
               "Under Invested",
               "No Change"
              )
           )
         )
      )
    )
```

Collapsed into a single line, that's this:

```
=IF(AND(K2>=Summary!$D$1,I2>Summary!$A$8,J2>0),"Poor Performer",IF(AND(J2=0,F2>30),"Pause",IF(AND(J2=0,F2<30,I2>10),"High Spender",IF(OR(AND(K2<=Summary!$D$1,E2<Summary!$A$13),AND(E2="-,K2<=Summary!$D$1)),"Low Traffic Boost",IF(K2<Summary!$C$1,"Under Invested","No Change")))))
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helps. I'll make it a point to split it out by line breaks so i can avoid missing parentheses :)

Comment: Excel also tries to help with that by color-coding the parentheses. In [this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itGUk.png), there are too many to have unique colors for all of them. It still helps a bit, though.